# Where to find a plugin folder?

Tags: neo4j, debian

I installed Neo4j on my Debian using [this](http://debian.neo4j.org/?_ga=1.100821001.92216559.1455034890) instructions. It seems, that Neo4j was installed as a service. Now I need to install a Spatial Plugin. But I can't understand, where to find a folder containing plugins (and other files, like database and logs, too) in case of such installation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you install Neo4j  from debian packages you'll find the plugins in `/var/lib/neo4j/plugins`.